# Reading in C in xCode errors

Tags: c

I am trying to read some user input in C (so taking in the user's first and last name, departure and arrival locations) but I am getting this error that the type of declaration I've made is inconsistent. I'm a little new to C still so bear with me as this may be a trivial thing.  Why the error?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void) {

  char lastName, firstName, depart, arrive;

  printf("Please enter passenger's last name: ");
  scanf("%s", &lastName);
  printf("Please enter passenger's first name: ");
  scanf("%s", &firstName);
  printf("Which airport are you departing from? ");
  scanf("%s", &depart);
  printf("Which airport will you be heading to? ");
  scanf("%s", &arrive);
  printf("LAST NAME: %s FIRST NAME: %s FROM: %s TO: %s", lastName,   
  firstName, depart, arrive);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: You cannot store a series of characters (a "string") in just one `char` variable, as it takes exactly one character only.

Comment: You've only allocated a single character to hold null terminated strings.  You have not allocated enough space.  And `printf` expects `char *` when processing `%s` but you are passing `int` (because `char` is promoted to `int` in the trailing arguments to `printf()`).

Comment: Same idea with the connoisseur of C @JonathanLeffler. In addition, you should take look at a C book for beginners.

Comment: @alk so I have to declare each on a separate line?

Comment: No (you don't have to declare on separate lines); you need to define arrays of `char` to hold strings (aka null-terminated arrays of `char`). And then you'll need to drop the & in the calls to `scanf`.

Comment: Also, please fix the question title and opening paragraph.  Both refer to scanning integers, but the code is reading (trying to read) strings.

Comment: Just a general comment: I'm not sure why my post has -3 downvotes. It is most definitely not offensive (maybe it's "annoying" if you're a C connoisseur) but it's really hard for me to return to this place for assistance when I see such things. Just my 2 cents. Thank you to those of who who have be gracious and humble in your help

Comment: *Any* introduction to working with strings you must have read, will mention that you need either a char array or a `char *` (pointing to valid memory) to work with strings. That's not "connaisseur" level, that is "C Strings 1-0-1".

Comment: Whatever man, other people have helped me out. Do me a favor pal, if you don't want to help just jog on.

Answer (score 2):

The `%s` format specifier expects the address of the first character in a destination buffer. This buffer will be filled with the next word. You pass the address of a `char`, but that char doesn't have enough space to store an entire string! One way to write the code that is more correct is:

```
char buf[32];
scanf("%s", buf);
```

`buf` decays into a pointer to its first element, so that `buf` can be filled with the next word.

However, using `scanf` is not recommended. The better approach is to use `fgets`.

```
char *fgets(char *s, int size, FILE *stream);
```

It reads the next line (of no more than `size-1` characters) from `stream` into the buffer pointed to by `s`. Any characters that exceed `size` are not added. It includes the newline in the string if there is space. This function is superior, because it avoids buffer overflows and also reads an entire line—not just the next word.

```
char buf[80];
fgets(buf, sizeof buf, stdin);
```

This is what you should be using to read text. Your program can be rewritten to:

```
#define MAXLNAME    80
#define MAXFNAME    80
#define MAXAIRPORT   3

int main()
{
    char lname[MAXLNAME + 1], fname[MAXFNAME + 1], 
         srcAirport[MAXAIRPORT + 1], destAirport[MAXAIRPORT + 1];

    printf("Last name\n");
    fgets(lname, sizeof lname, stdin);

    printf("First name\n");
    fgets(fname, sizeof fname, stdin);

    printf("Source airport\n");
    fgets(srcAirport, sizeof srcAirport, stdin);

    printf("Destination airport\n");
    fgets(destAirport, sizeof destAirport, stdin);

    return 0;
}
```

However, fgets has a problem. It stores the trailing newline in the destination buffer. We can solve this easily though.

```
/* remnl: Overwrite trailing newline from fgets with zero-terminator */
void remnl(char *buf)
{
    size_t n = strlen(buf);
    if (n > 0 && buf[n - 1] == '\n')
        buf[n - 1] = '\0';
}
```

Then, before you print out the buffers, you can call `remnl` on each buffer

```
remnl(lname);
remnl(fname);
remnl(srcAirport);
remnl(destAirport);
```

Comment: I have mixed feelings about the "`scanf()` is not recommended" comment.  I have serious misgivings about not removing the newlines stored by `fgets()`.

Comment: Example correct code would be `char buf[32];
scanf("%31s", buf);`

Comment: @chux That's why I propose fgets--to not only solve the buffer overflows but also because it isnt limited to a single word. Overall, `fgets` is the better solution even with the `%31s` specifier. Also, fgets **forces** you to supply a limit, but in scanf its optional

Comment: You seem to want the safest input possible. With `fgets()`, it is imperative that you clean up leftover characters in the buffer. If not, the user can find many ways to deviate from the intended behavior. What happens if you change `MAXLNAME` and `MAXFNAME` to 5? Use something like _1234567_ and _123456_ for input. For safer input you should clear the buffer if you don't find `\n` in the input (the user will have entered more than allowed and the [enter] wouldn't have been read); otherwise, remove `\n` from the input. `fflush()` not allowed due to undefined behavior when clearing the buffer.

Comment: Note: `size_t n = strlen(buf) - 1; if (buf[n] == '\n')` allows a hacker to exploit code by letting a null character as the first character as `buf[(size_t)-1]` occurs.  `size_t n = strlen(buf);
    if (n > 0 && buf[n-1] == '\n') ...` prevents that.

Comment: @chux fixed [15 chars]

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out by others in the comments, you did not allocate enough spaces for your strings. Here is a possible fix:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main (void) {

    char *lastName, *firstName, *depart, *arrive;

    printf("Please enter passenger's last name: ");
    scanf("%ms", &lastName);
    printf("Please enter passenger's first name: ");
    scanf("%ms", &firstName);
    printf("Which airport are you departing from? ");
    scanf("%ms", &depart);
    printf("Which airport will you be heading to? ");
    scanf("%ms", &arrive);
    printf("LAST NAME: %s FIRST NAME: %s FROM: %s TO: %s\n", lastName,   
            firstName, depart, arrive);

    free(lastName);
    free(firstName);
    free(depart);
    free(arrive);

    return 0;
}
```

If you are using `m` modifier as a length modifier for `%s`, then `scanf` will allocate the necessary space for your input, which you may not know the length in advance, and you need to free these spaces by yourself.  By the way, this feature is part of POSIX, but not in C standard yet.

See [scanf(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/scanf.3.html) for further explanation of `m` modifier.

Comment: I think you need to explain the `%ms` notation a bit more.  It also isn't the most obvious solution to the problem, though I grant you it has merits.  It is POSIX standard, but not standard C.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Answer updated, thank you for the suggestion.

Comment: I believe an answer using standard features *only* would be more beneficial to the OP. It's not as if you "need" to do it this way.

Comment: @RadLexus That's why I said that is a /possible/ fix :-)

Comment: I've modified my code to include the m modifier as well as the free method but I'm getting a SIGABRT error now:

Comment: @HassanKamara Have you tried to copy and paste the code in my answer? Did that work for you?

Comment: @HassanKamara Please note that I also changed the declarations of `lastName`, etc.

Comment: Yeah it's the same SIGABRT error, its specifically pointing to free(lastName);

Comment: @HassanKamara Then I am not sure what's wrong. It works for me, and am pretty sure the code itself is correct.

Comment: I've tried it in xCode and then Eclipse but it's the same error. I'll try in an online compiler and see if I get the same problems

Comment: @HassanKamara I tried it in [codechef](https://www.codechef.com/ide) with gcc 4.9.2, and it works.

Comment: So it works, I'm not sure why its not working in xCode or Eclipse but it works in an online compiler. Thanks for taking the time to explain things. Safe ✌️

Comment: @HassanKamara Maybe the libc  in your environment does not support `m` modifier. If that's the case, you should use stackptr's solution.

Comment: @HassanKamara: Did you read the man page for `scanf()` on Mac?  AFAICS, it doesn't mention support for `%ms` or any equivalent mechanism, so this won't work for you (or me).  You _must_ know how to read the man pages on each system you work on — they're usually the best authority (short of looking at the code implementing the functions) on what is and is not supported on the given machine.